# __webpack_require__ is not defined. Here map bundle doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, webpack, here-api, heremaps

I've got an issue inside web worker when tried to use `@here/maps-api-for-javascript`.

I think that happens since the webpack changes the code that runs inside the web worker.

the initial part of the bundle (mapsjs.bundle.js):

```js
e = "undefined" != typeof globalThis ? globalThis : "undefined" != typeof window ? window : "undefined" != typeof global ? global : "undefined" != typeof self ? self : {};
```

after webpack build:

```
e="undefined"!=typeof globalThis?globalThis:"undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof __webpack_require__.g?__webpack_require__.g:"undefined"
```

In this case inside the web worker, we don't have the `__webpack_require__` variable. Looks like I have to configure the webpack to prevent it.

The example from the official site doesn't work too. Same error. https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.22.0/dev_guide/topics/get-started-bundling.html

But all works fine if we add the here-maps API as an inline script in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the fact that Webpack 5 now by default renames the "global" variable. The guide was written when the webpack 4 was the main version.
The following option in the *webpack.config* will do the trick.

```
node: { global: false }
```

This webpack.config works for me:

```
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

 module.exports = {
     mode: 'production',
     entry: {
         index: './index.js'
     },
     output: {
         publicPath: './out/',
         path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out'),
         filename: '[name].js',
         chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js'
     },
     optimization: {
         minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
         /*chunkFilter: (chunk) => {
             // Exclude mapsjs chunk from the minification as it is already minified
             if (/mapsjs/.test(chunk.name)) return false;
             return true;
         }*/
         exclude: "mapsjs.bundle.js"
         })],
     },
     node: {
         global: false
     }
 };
```

Comment: I'm running into this problem with create-react-app, where the webpack configuration is hidden away, any guidance about what to do here (no pun intended)?

Comment: Also have a similar problem. What can I do with create-react-app 5.0 that uses Webpack 5 by default, where no configuration file is located. Is it possible to use CRA 5.0 and avoid the eject process to add the config file like that?

Comment: If I do this then I have the following issue:

`async_iterator.js?undefined:48 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: global is not defined at ./node_modules/stream-browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js (async_iterator.js?undefined:48:1)`

Answer (score 0):

I just changed react-scripts version from 5.0.0 to 4.0.3 on packge.json file
then rm -rf node_modules and npm i to reinstall

It "fixed" the issue, at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with application but still have problem how to setup this maps for Storybook with `@storybook/builder-webpack5`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed Storybook issue with node global. Problem is with using `@storybook/addon-interactions` because `jest-mock` relying on the node global variable. To fix this storybook should have `.storybook/preview-head.html` file and contain in this file following code:

```
<script>
  window.global = window;
</script>
```

Comment: It sounds like there should be a better way to approach this from webpack.config